# How to use play-plugins-mailer with Play 2.3 and Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to use the play plugin for sending emails:

https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer

I have followed the instructions as found on github: added the dependency to build.sbt, created play.plugins with the specified content (do I need to register the file somehow)?

but I get a compilation error:

```
object mailer is not a member of package play.api.libs
```

when trying to import

```
import play.api.libs.mailer._
```

I get another compilation error on

```
val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email
```

MailerPlugin and use are not found.

How to get this working?

Note: the plugin is correctly downloaded (I can find it in my .ivy2 directory), but it is not listed as a dependency in my application.

My build.sbt file:

```
name := ...

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")

//"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.31"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.24",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.8.0",
  "com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.3.1",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
)

fork in Test := false

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

And my play.plugins contains only:

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

UPDATE:
I've downloaded the sample project from https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer
and tried to compile using sbt. It failed with exactly the same problem.

Comment: I found sbt/activator rubbish when adding new dependencies. Sometimes new deps are not attached to classpath. Try recreating project configuration with `eclipse` or `idea` task.

Comment: @MonCalamari Who says the OP is even using an IDE?

Comment: @jfu If you're using activator/sbt, did you `reload` your project after added the dependency to `build.sbt`?

Comment: I've tried reload. I've also tried to run sbt from commandline. I get the same issue in all cases

Comment: Did you try `activator clean`? Can you post your `build.sbt`? `play.plugins` ?

Comment: I've added build.sbt and play.plugins to the original post. I do not use activator (just sbt), but I've tried sbt clean multiple times

Comment: Try deleting the `target` directories? Does the sample application work for you? https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/tree/master/sample

Comment: @m-z No, the sample application fails with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is somehow with the version of plugin that is available in the typesafe repo:

I've built the plugin from sources, published it to my local repository and then everything compiled fine.

In the `build.sbt` of the sample app there is:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("LocalIvy", file(Path.userHome + File.separator + ".ivy2" + File.separator + "local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

So it looks like the authors also had problems in compiling the app using the plugin deployed to the official repository.

UPDATE:
Well, it compiled fine, but then failed at runtime with  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin`

UPDATE 2:
The sample `play.plugins` is also wrong, the correct one should be:

```
1500:play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

and then eveyrthing finally works

Comment: Looks like the published version doesn't reflect the new namespace. It's still appearing within the `com.typesafe.plugin` namespace. I've filed an issue on github: https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

The README is up to date with the latest development (upcoming version). 
As of 19/12/2014, the latest version released and available in the Typesafe repository is 2.3.1. If you want to use this version you need to refer to the README in the v2.3.1 tag: https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/tree/v2.3.1

For the upcoming version we have decided to break compatibility to move the Play mailer into its own package and provide a better implementation. That's the reason why the documentation in the master branch is not working with version 2.3.1.

Comment: Well the README doesn't match latest development either as its referring to "com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.3.1" as the dependency to import and plugin config matches the 2.3.1 namespace but has sample code that doesn't work on 2.3.1. Wasted a bit of time with it. Thanks for link though as that did help.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, we took some time to complete the transition. We just released "2.4.0-RC1" and cleaned up a bit the README.

Comment: Mogztter, I am having a problem installing and configuring the play-mailer for scala pluggin, please can you explain how I can go about this ?