# How to install SecureSocial on Play Frame work 2.3.8?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3, securesocial

I have been working on learning how to use the Play framework.  It is my understanding that plugins can be use to add functionality that others have developed.  Maybe I should be calling it a module?  I read that SercureSocial is one of the best modules available for authentication.  But the documentation isn't really getting me anywhere.  Can someone help me understand how to add the master-snapshot to my existing java project?

Lets assume that I performed
activator new my-first-app play-scala
activator eclipse
The I imported into eclipse the project

The next step is to try to follow directions from the following url

http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html

After reading that I am still lost.

There is no Build.scala file, but I see there is a build.sbt file. Do I add this block to the build.sbt file?

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
val appName         = "my-first-app"
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
    "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
)
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)
```

After copying the block above, I created the ply.plugins file in the conf folder.  Then I copied all the plugins to the file and saved

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
9994:securesocial.core.DefaultAuthenticatorStore
9995:securesocial.core.DefaultIdGenerator
9996:securesocial.core.providers.utils.DefaultPasswordValidator
9997:securesocial.controllers.DefaultTemplatesPlugin
9998:your.user.Service.Implementation <-- Important: You need to change this
9999:securesocial.core.providers.utils.BCryptPasswordHasher
10000:securesocial.core.providers.TwitterProvider
10001:securesocial.core.providers.FacebookProvider
10002:securesocial.core.providers.GoogleProvider
10003:securesocial.core.providers.LinkedInProvider
10004:securesocial.core.providers.UsernamePasswordProvider
10005:securesocial.core.providers.GitHubProvider
10006:securesocial.core.providers.FoursquareProvider
10007:securesocial.core.providers.XingProvider
10008:securesocial.core.providers.VkProvider
10009:securesocial.core.providers.InstagramProvider
```

Next, I copy all the routes into the routes file

```
# Login page
GET     /login                      securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
GET     /logout                     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout

# User Registration and password handling 
GET     /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.startSignUp
POST    /signup                     securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleStartSignUp
GET     /signup/:token              securesocial.controllers.Registration.signUp(token)
POST    /signup/:token              securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleSignUp(token)
GET     /reset                      securesocial.controllers.Registration.startResetPassword
POST    /reset                      securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleStartResetPassword
GET     /reset/:token               securesocial.controllers.Registration.resetPassword(token)
POST    /reset/:token               securesocial.controllers.Registration.handleResetPassword(token)
GET     /password                   securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.page
POST    /password                   securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.handlePasswordChange

# Providers entry points
GET     /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticate(provider)
POST    /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticateByPost(provider)
GET     /not-authorized             securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.notAuthorized
```

I then try to run the project and I get the following error

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: ws.securesocial#securesocial;2.1.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          ws.securesocial:securesocial:2.1.4 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: ws.securesocial#securesocial;2.1.4:not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: ws.securesocial#securesocial;2.1.4: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: Did you read the installation guide? http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html

Comment: Yes.   Do I have to change the line "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4" to something else and where do I add it?  Is it added to build.sbt?  Is it added in the block:   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
  
)

Comment: I added more details regarding my problem

Answer (score 3):

I've been going through this myself the last couple days.  At this point in time, I suggest you ignore the documentation.  It is not up to date (documentation is for 2, but 3 seems to be needed for play 2.3.x).  Stuff like the play.plugins send you down the wrong path.

Piecing together an installation for putting M3 on 2.3.X has been rough, but I do think I have it working in Java.   These resources have been helpful to me.  Pull stuff like your .sbt settings from the sample.

First, read the [high level overview](http://www.filtercode.com/play/play-scala-securesocial). Second, [clone the sample](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/java/demo) and get it to run. This 
[SO on running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110389/how-do-you-run-the-securesocial-demo) is helpful.  Third, migrate code from the sample into your local tree.  Once you get that going, you may see there is no styling.  See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/securesocial/_1umOEL_uNA) for info on how to get the css/js showing up.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone help me understand how to add the master-snapshot to my
>   existing java project?

I have only tried with the Scala version and not Java, but I hope the following helps a little bit.

In your build.sbt file add the following line to you libraryDependencies:

```
"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
```

> There is no Build.scala file, but I see there is a build.sbt file. Do
>   I add this block to the build.sbt file?

The only other thing you need to add to build.sbt is the Sonatype OSS Snapshots repository URL:

```
resolvers += 
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

> After copying the block above, I created the ply.plugins file in the
>   conf folder. Then I copied all the plugins to the file and saved

The only plugin you need configured in the play.plugins file is the CommonsMailerPlugin:

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

> Next, I copy all the routes into the routes file

Try the below as an example instead of what you had which is based on an older version of securesocal:

```
# your secure page
GET        /                        @controllers.Application.index
# securesocial routes
GET        /login                   @securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
GET        /logout                  @securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout
->         /auth                    securesocial.Routes
```

In order to get a working example running you need the following:

- securesocial.conf file created in the conf folder and included in your application.conf file so it gets picked up
- InMemoryUserService.scala
- Global.scala
- Your Secure Application controller
- Your Secure page

**securesocial.conf**
https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/scala/demo/conf/securesocial.conf

You would need to configure your smtp mail settings and any securesocial configuration.

**InMemoryUserService**

Scala
https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/scala/demo/app/service/InMemoryUserService.scala

Java
https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/java/demo/app/service/InMemoryUserService.java

```
/**
 * Copyright 2012 Jorge Aliss (jaliss at gmail dot com) - twitter: @jaliss
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */
package service

import play.api.Logger
import securesocial.core._
import securesocial.core.providers.{ UsernamePasswordProvider, MailToken }
import scala.concurrent.Future
import securesocial.core.services.{ UserService, SaveMode }

/**
 * A Sample In Memory user service in Scala
 *
 * IMPORTANT: This is just a sample and not suitable for a production environment since
 * it stores everything in memory.
 */
class InMemoryUserService extends UserService[DemoUser] {
  val logger = Logger("application.controllers.InMemoryUserService")

  //
  var users = Map[(String, String), DemoUser]()
  //private var identities = Map[String, BasicProfile]()
  private var tokens = Map[String, MailToken]()

  def find(providerId: String, userId: String): Future[Option[BasicProfile]] = {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled) {
      logger.debug("users = %s".format(users))
    }
    val result = for (
      user <- users.values;
      basicProfile <- user.identities.find(su => su.providerId == providerId && su.userId == userId)
    ) yield {
      basicProfile
    }
    Future.successful(result.headOption)
  }

  def findByEmailAndProvider(email: String, providerId: String): Future[Option[BasicProfile]] = {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled) {
      logger.debug("users = %s".format(users))
    }
    val someEmail = Some(email)
    val result = for (
      user <- users.values;
      basicProfile <- user.identities.find(su => su.providerId == providerId && su.email == someEmail)
    ) yield {
      basicProfile
    }
    Future.successful(result.headOption)
  }

  private def findProfile(p: BasicProfile) = {
    users.find {
      case (key, value) if value.identities.exists(su => su.providerId == p.providerId && su.userId == p.userId) => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  private def updateProfile(user: BasicProfile, entry: ((String, String), DemoUser)): Future[DemoUser] = {
    val identities = entry._2.identities
    val updatedList = identities.patch(identities.indexWhere(i => i.providerId == user.providerId && i.userId == user.userId), Seq(user), 1)
    val updatedUser = entry._2.copy(identities = updatedList)
    users = users + (entry._1 -> updatedUser)
    Future.successful(updatedUser)
  }

  def save(user: BasicProfile, mode: SaveMode): Future[DemoUser] = {
    mode match {
      case SaveMode.SignUp =>
        val newUser = DemoUser(user, List(user))
        users = users + ((user.providerId, user.userId) -> newUser)
        Future.successful(newUser)
      case SaveMode.LoggedIn =>
        // first see if there is a user with this BasicProfile already.
        findProfile(user) match {
          case Some(existingUser) =>
            updateProfile(user, existingUser)

          case None =>
            val newUser = DemoUser(user, List(user))
            users = users + ((user.providerId, user.userId) -> newUser)
            Future.successful(newUser)
        }

      case SaveMode.PasswordChange =>
        findProfile(user).map { entry => updateProfile(user, entry) }.getOrElse(
          // this should not happen as the profile will be there
          throw new Exception("missing profile)")
        )
    }
  }

  def link(current: DemoUser, to: BasicProfile): Future[DemoUser] = {
    if (current.identities.exists(i => i.providerId == to.providerId && i.userId == to.userId)) {
      Future.successful(current)
    } else {
      val added = to :: current.identities
      val updatedUser = current.copy(identities = added)
      users = users + ((current.main.providerId, current.main.userId) -> updatedUser)
      Future.successful(updatedUser)
    }
  }

  def saveToken(token: MailToken): Future[MailToken] = {
    Future.successful {
      tokens += (token.uuid -> token)
      token
    }
  }

  def findToken(token: String): Future[Option[MailToken]] = {
    Future.successful { tokens.get(token) }
  }

  def deleteToken(uuid: String): Future[Option[MailToken]] = {
    Future.successful {
      tokens.get(uuid) match {
        case Some(token) =>
          tokens -= uuid
          Some(token)
        case None => None
      }
    }
  }

  //  def deleteTokens(): Future {
  //    tokens = Map()
  //  }

  def deleteExpiredTokens() {
    tokens = tokens.filter(!_._2.isExpired)
  }

  override def updatePasswordInfo(user: DemoUser, info: PasswordInfo): Future[Option[BasicProfile]] = {
    Future.successful {
      for (
        found <- users.values.find(_ == user);
        identityWithPasswordInfo <- found.identities.find(_.providerId == UsernamePasswordProvider.UsernamePassword)
      ) yield {
        val idx = found.identities.indexOf(identityWithPasswordInfo)
        val updated = identityWithPasswordInfo.copy(passwordInfo = Some(info))
        val updatedIdentities = found.identities.patch(idx, Seq(updated), 1)
        val updatedEntry = found.copy(identities = updatedIdentities)
        users = users + ((updatedEntry.main.providerId, updatedEntry.main.userId) -> updatedEntry)
        updated
      }
    }
  }

  override def passwordInfoFor(user: DemoUser): Future[Option[PasswordInfo]] = {
    Future.successful {
      for (
        found <- users.values.find(u => u.main.providerId == user.main.providerId && u.main.userId == user.main.userId);
        identityWithPasswordInfo <- found.identities.find(_.providerId == UsernamePasswordProvider.UsernamePassword)
      ) yield {
        identityWithPasswordInfo.passwordInfo.get
      }
    }
  }
}

// a simple User class that can have multiple identities
case class DemoUser(main: BasicProfile, identities: List[BasicProfile])
```

**Global.scala**

Scala
https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/scala/demo/app/Global.scala

Java
https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/samples/java/demo/app/Global.java

```
/**
 * Copyright 2014 Jorge Aliss (jaliss at gmail dot com) - twitter: @jaliss
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 */
import controllers.CustomRoutesService
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor
import securesocial.core.RuntimeEnvironment
import service.{ DemoUser, MyEventListener, InMemoryUserService }

object Global extends play.api.GlobalSettings {

  /**
   * The runtime environment for this sample app.
   */
  object MyRuntimeEnvironment extends RuntimeEnvironment.Default[DemoUser] {
    override implicit val executionContext = play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.defaultContext
    override lazy val routes = new CustomRoutesService()
    override lazy val userService: InMemoryUserService = new InMemoryUserService()
    override lazy val eventListeners = List(new MyEventListener())
  }

  /**
   * An implementation that checks if the controller expects a RuntimeEnvironment and
   * passes the instance to it if required.
   *
   * This can be replaced by any DI framework to inject it differently.
   *
   * @param controllerClass
   * @tparam A
   * @return
   */
  override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {
    val instance = controllerClass.getConstructors.find { c =>
      val params = c.getParameterTypes
      params.length == 1 && params(0) == classOf[RuntimeEnvironment[DemoUser]]
    }.map {
      _.asInstanceOf[Constructor[A]].newInstance(MyRuntimeEnvironment)
    }
    instance.getOrElse(super.getControllerInstance(controllerClass))
  }
}
```

**Secure Application controller**

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

import securesocial.core._
import service.DemoUser

class Application(override implicit val env: RuntimeEnvironment[DemoUser]) extends SecureSocial[DemoUser] {

  def index = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index(request.user.main))
  }
}
```

**Secure page** - index.scala.html

```
@(user: securesocial.core.BasicProfile)(implicit request: RequestHeader, env: securesocial.core.RuntimeEnvironment[service.DemoUser])

@main("Secure Page") {
    <h2>User Id:@user.userId</h2>
    <hr>
    <a class="btn" href="@securesocial.controllers.routes.LoginPage.logout()">Logout</a>
}
```

Comment: how to config play plugin ?

Comment: Do you mean what goes in the play.plugins file or how to configure secure social? The only line you need in the conf/play.plugins file is: 1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin. Secure social provides a default securesocial.conf file for you to edit. There are many options there to choose from

Comment: you say that `The only plugin you need configured in the play.plugins file is the CommonsMailerPlugin:` but I do not know how to config that.

Comment: I have the smtp settings configured in the application.conf file and a library dependency added in the build.sbt file. You can view the play start application template it has an example of how the plugin is configured: https://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/PlayStartApp. Also view this stackoverflow page as there seems to be some issue over the package depending on the version of Play being used: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27132985/349842

Answer (score 0):

Well... `libraryDependencies` is a `SettingKey[ Seq[ ModuleId ] ]`.

Now, `SettingKey[ Seq[ ModuleId ] ]` can be seen as something similar to a `Seq` or `List` and it provides similar kind of functionalities.

So... you can just add your new dependencies to it, just like you will add to any other `Seq` or `List`.

```
libraryDependencies += "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4"
```