# How do you run the SecureSocial demo?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3, securesocial

I downloaded securesocial-master.zip from https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master

1.After extracting, change directory

```
cd C:\Users\ddd\play\securesocial-master
```

2.run activator

```
C:\Users\ddd\play\securesocial-master\activator run
```

The Error message:

```
C:\Users\DDD\workspace\securesocial-master>activator run
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\DDD\workspace\securesocial-m
aster\project
[info] Set current project to SecureSocial-parent (in build file:/C:/Users/DDD
/workspace/securesocial-master/)
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/DDD/workspace/securesocial-master/}root...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.1 ..
.
  [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[info] Done updating.
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last root/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (root/compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 1, 2015 10:02:06 AM
```

Comment: You should address your question to the author of this stuff.

Comment: Which version of Play exactly do you use? `activator` command indicates at least 2.3.x, while on the author's page there is a note _Supports Play versions 2.1.x, 2.0.x and 1.x._ - http://securesocial.ws/

Comment: Ya, the author states that one should use the master-SNAPSHOT for 2.3.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to you input information:

1. cd to

> C:\Users\ddd\play\securesocial-master

2.run activator from the root directory

> C:\Users\ddd\play\securesocial-master\activator

3.type command project and press TAB key, ane you can choose demo:

> > project javaDemo

4.Run this demo

> [java-demo] $ run

result

> (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

P.S.

use help for more details

> [java-demo] $ help project

Comment: `activator run` should be `activator`

Comment: Lucas, when I try step 2, I get an error message.  I'll put the message in my main question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `sbt` from the project root, then use the command `project javaDemo` to navigate to the java demo, then `run` to actually run it.