# Which document or sample should I refer to start securesocial 3.0 with play framwork 2.3.x in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, securesocial

Environment
- Play 2.3.8
- sbt 0.13.8
- java 1.8
- scala 2.11
- Mac OSX 10.9
- secure social (latest 'master snapshot')

---

I just tried using secure social 3.0 with play framework 2.3.x in scala.
I found two reference as following.

- Official document on official site. But it was old version, mentioned in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ja#!starred/securesocial/XxGidexMjtk). So i can't make sense how it works.
- I found sample application on [github.](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial) And cloned it. But it doesn't work. Compiler said that /securesocial/samples/scala/demo/project/plugins.sbt have problem.

  "error: not found: value Common
  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % Common.playVersion)"

I'll leave sample code here.
plugins.sbt

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % Common.playVersion)
```

So, which document should I refer or how to solve the problem on the above?
I need something to import to plugins.sbt?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sample mentioned above is working by following steps.

1. Run `sbt` from the project root
2. Use the command `project scalaDemo` to navigate to the scala demo
3. `run`

[How do you run the SecureSocial demo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110389/how-do-you-run-the-securesocial-demo)

Comment: it does seem to work from the command line but it crashes horribly when trying to import it to intellij